# randomized jQuery.sortable, is dropped item in the correct spot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am building this as a self check for online students. The real content is ordering historic events.

Right now I have an ordered list that is randomized and then turned into a sortable list. I even have it set up so that when any item is dropped, it checks to see if the whole thing is in the correct order. See the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kking/ptgxedhh/2/

```
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
}
var correctOrder = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
$("#sortable").sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        console.log("item dropped");
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        console.log(order);
        for (i = 0; i < correctOrder.length; i++) {
            if (correctOrder[i] == order[i]) {
                console.log(i + " correct!");
            } else {
                console.log(i + " incorrect!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

What I need it to do next, is check to see if the last dropped item is in the correct spot. I don't have any clue where to start, other then I know it belongs in the stop function. I'm not sure if it's better to use my arrays, and ask if the item dropped is in the same position as the correctOrder array.. or some other method. To be truthful, I'm not sure how I would even get the array position of that dropped item.

Any help or pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can the dropped index with `ui.item.index()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
    var correctOrder = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            console.log("item dropped");
            var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');

            var droppedIndex = ui.item.index();
            if (order[droppedIndex] === correctOrder[droppedIndex]) {
                alert('Correct!');
            } else {
               alert('Incorrect.');
            }
                
            for (i = 0; i < correctOrder.length; i++) {
                if (correctOrder[i] === order[i]) {
                    console.log(i + " correct!");
                } else {
                    console.log(i + " incorrect!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
 ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 li {
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 5px;
     width: 150px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="one">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="two">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="three">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="four">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="five">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="six">6</li>
</ul>
```